# image not shown in xampp in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, xampp

I am using xampp in ubuntu 12.10. My problem is, when I open folder from htdocs images can't be show but it works well in windows xp and even if it works when I open this folder normally without running apache server that means that when I use "localhost/somefolder/index.html" It's images don't show but it works well the same file if I use "file:///opt/lampp/htdocs/somefolder/index.html"

Comment: Probably to do with something in your .htacess but we need to know more first: what exactly happens when you try viewing the images folder, can you view individual images, and are you attempting this from a web browser or file manager?

Comment: No type of image is shown, no individual images ..

Comment: And is this when you are trying to view the image in the browser?

Comment: yes, you are right. But when I open file with browser normally not running apache server or xampp, it works fine.

Comment: What file path are you trying to use?

Comment: "http://localhost/somefolder/index.html" This is not work but if I use "file:///opt/lampp/htdocs/somefolder/index.html" works well

Comment: Are you sure that you've started LAMP properly? You've opened a terminal and then typed `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp` start ?

Comment: Also, have you got `http://` before `localhost`?

Comment: yes, but it still no result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have permission to change information. So I change permission of that folder. I do the following ::

```
1) **cd **

2) **cd /opt/lampp/htdocs**

3) **chmod 777 * -R**
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a couple of times. Mine worked when I changed the file permission to:

```
 chmod -R 777 path-to-your-folder
```